# How to change buttons inside react-table using if and else statement?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

My reactJS web page has this react-table with 2 buttons inside, I want to change those button when a cell column status changes its value.

```
render() {
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "Actions",
      accessor: "ID",
      Cell: ({ value }) => (
        <div style={buttonTablestyle}>
          <Button
            bsStyle="info"
            onClick={() => {
              if (window.confirm("You are approving this request after you press OK...")) {
                this.updateFunctionYES(value);
              }
            }}
          >
            Approve
          </Button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Button
            bsStyle="warning"
            onClick={() => {
              if (window.confirm("You are rejecting this request after you press OK...")) {
                this.updateFunctionNO(value);
              }
            }}
          >
            Reject
          </Button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: That means you just need first button if there is a special condition and if it's changed the other button should appear but first one doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

### Conditional Styling

The most basic way for conditional styling is to use state and style-objects, which will be explained below. Noteworthy alternatives for conditional styling with prettier syntax and better readability are [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) and [styled components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components).

**1) define the state**

whenever you want to change a style depending on a value this value should be part of the state, since any change in the state triggers a re-render

**2) define style outside the render function**

when re-rendering you want to access the styles without re-defining them each time.

**3) assign style depending on state**

you then assign your needed style within a ternary operator, if statement or switch to use it within your html element.

**Example**

```js
// define styles you want to use depending on state
const green = {
  background: 'green'
}

const red = {
  background: 'red'
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toggle: false
  }

  handleClick() {
    // change state on click
    this.setState({
      toggle: !this.state.toggle
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    // state change triggers re-render
    // define style to be used depending on state
    let myStyle = this.state.toggle ? green : red;
    
    return <div>
      <div style={myStyle}>MyApp</div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>click me</button>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

### Conditional Displaying

If you want to hide/show conditionally you can add `display: none` to one of the styles or you use the state to only return the jsx you want to display.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toggle: false
  }

  handleClick() {
    // change state on click
    this.setState({
      toggle: !this.state.toggle
    });
  }

  render() {
    // state change triggers re-render
    let element1 = <div>element1</div>;
    let element2 = <div>element2</div>;
    // define object to be used depending on state
    let elementToUse = this.state.toggle ? element1 : element2;

    return <div>
      {elementToUse}
      <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>click me</button>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```